# PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES (multiple bind & limit)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've just ran into interesting issue. I need to specify one variable in parameters array but bind it for every occurence in SQL query, I've achieved this using this attribute: `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);`. But when I use this, another query with LIMIT in it doesn't work, because I need to specify `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);`    to get it working properly (so PDO handles it as INT, not STRING). I also tried to use **bindValue**    function in combination with **PDO::PARAM_INT** but still It doesn't handle LIMIT value as INT.

Comment: Please show a sample of what you're trying to achieve. There should be absolutely no need to switch between different emulation settings, emulation should always be off unless absolutely inevitable. That just means you need to formulate your queries in a way that works without emulation/with either form. You're just hitting an edge case there, and without seeing what exactly that is it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I use this, another query with LIMIT in it doesn't work

You can change the emulation mode on the fly, turning it on and off when required.

> I also tried to use bindValue function in combination with PDO::PARAM_INT but still It doesn't handle LIMIT value as INT.

Make sure that you did cast the value to an int explicitly, as [PDO doesn't cast them for PDO::PARAM_INT](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit).

Answer (score 0):

```
array (size=5)
  ':audit_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  ':audit_id1' => string '1' (length=1)
  ':audit_id2' => string '1' (length=1)
  ':audit_id3' => string '1' (length=1)
  ':audit_id4' => string '1' (length=1)
```

**db_query:**

```
SELECT TYP,OSOBA,o.JMENO FROM ( (SELECT 'd.auditor_prihlasen' AS TYP, prihlasena_osoba_id AS osoba FROM dotaznik d WHERE audit_id = :audit_id AND prihlasena_osoba_id > 0) UNION (SELECT 'd.auditor_vyroba' AS TYP, auditor_vyroba_id AS osoba FROM dotaznik d WHERE audit_id = :audit_id1 AND auditor_vyroba_id > 0) UNION (SELECT 'd.auditor_kvalita' AS TYP, auditor_kvalita_id AS osoba FROM dotaznik d WHERE audit_id = :audit_id2 AND auditor_kvalita_id > 0) UNION (SELECT 'od.odpovedna_osoba' AS TYP, odpovedna_osoba_id AS osoba FROM odpoved od WHERE tema_id IN(SELECT id FROM tema WHERE audit_id = :audit_id3)) UNION (SELECT 'od.odpovedna_osoba' AS TYP, odpovedna_osoba_id_puvodni AS osoba FROM odpoved od WHERE tema_id IN(SELECT id FROM tema WHERE audit_id = :audit_id4) AND odpovedna_osoba_id_puvodni > 0) ) tbls, osoba o WHERE o.id = osoba GROUP BY typ, osoba, jmeno
```

I want query to run without audit_id1, audit_id2 etc.. so all of them would use just one variable audit_id

Comment: Please **update your question** with new information, don't post it as answer.